# JQuery UI: Accordion is not a functon

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, html5boilerplate

ANSWER:

> It turns out that that at the bottom of the HTML generated by HTML5 boileplate there is a call to the CDN for JQuery, so it unloaded JQuery UI.

I've got a HTML5 Boilerplate project that will eventually be served via Django. For the time being I'm just trying to get my front-end looking nice.

I've got JQuery and JQuery UI linked in my  but and JQuery functions look like they're working but for some reason it refuses to acknowledge that accordion exists. I get "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).accordion is not a function"

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>DaCara</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $(".news_container").accordion();
    });
    </script>
</head>
```

Div definition:

```
            <div class="news_container">
          <h3>Test News, please ignore</h3>
          <div class="news_item">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.  Ut
              gravida at est non blandit. Maecenas elementum ullamcorper
              rutrum. Suspendisse  dignissim porta congue. Mauris finibus
              neque diam,  ullamcorper sodales est suscipit a.
            </p>
          </div>
          <h3>Test News2, please ignore</h3>
          <div class="news_item">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.  Ut
              gravida at est non blandit. Maecenas elementum ullamcorper
              rutrum. Suspendisse  dignissim porta congue. Mauris finibus
              neque diam,  ullamcorper sodales est suscipit a.
            </p>
          </div>
          <h3>Test News3, please ignore</h3>
          <div class="news_item">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.  Ut
              gravida at est non blandit. Maecenas elementum ullamcorper
              rutrum. Suspendisse  dignissim porta congue. Mauris finibus
              neque diam,  ullamcorper sodales est suscipit a.
            </p>
          </div>
          <h3>Test New4, please ignore</h3>
          <div class="news_item">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.  Ut
              gravida at est non blandit. Maecenas elementum ullamcorper
              rutrum. Suspendisse  dignissim porta congue. Mauris finibus
              neque diam,  ullamcorper sodales est suscipit a.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this is what you have? At minimum, jQuery would return a jQuery collection containing the matched elements. Even if it doesn't find anything, it'll still return that collection, albeit an empty one. Even empty, `accordion()` should still be callable. The conclusion is that `$()` isn't returning a jQuery collection. This implies you have some kind of typo in there or that jQuery isn't being attached to `$`. Though how this might happen but still allow the onready shorthand is a mystery.

A jsfiddle demonstrating this is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ype5rrat/). Note that despite no content, `accordian()` works without issue.

Comment: I don't think so. news container contains 5 sets of <h3><div> elements as outlined here: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#default

I'll add the news container html to check.

Comment: If I do $(".news_container") in the console it returns the div along with all the pairs. So it at least seems to be finding them.

Comment: Oddly enough if I paste my div from above into the jsfiddle you added, it works.

This leaves me to believe I must have some sort of import error somewhere. I've tried multiple ways of importing. Downloading and referencing local files and CDN however.

Comment: @Sevvy325 It shouldn't be returning the div as an element, it should be returning an object. The object will be a jQuery collection, an array-like object, and the matched elements will be referenced as numbered propeties in the object. Using your code, this can be seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ype5rrat/2/).

Comment: @Sevvy325 I don't know if it's relevant, but jQuery isn't the only library that uses `$`. prototype and MooTools also use it. If these or something else that has functionality similar to jQuery is used, you might get this issue. Maybe try using `jQuery` instead of `$`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111363/discussion-between-sevvy325-and-ouroborus).

Comment: For posterity: "Below head HTML5 Boilerplate loads in JQuery for the Google Analytics bit" (from Sevvy325 in discussion) and overwrights OP's jQuery/jQuery UI global.